# Desktop icon's turn red randomly when hovered over in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card, icons, desktop-customization, display-driver

This happens so randomly, I wish I could explain more. Sometimes, all of a sudden, when I move my mouse over some icons on my desktop in Windows 10, their backgrounds turn red. As well as the desktop background, it sometimes turns to a solid color of red as well... So weird! Could it be a driver issue? The display adaptor I have is the EVGA GeForce GTX 750 Ti. Below are some snips of the issues I've been having.

[image]

Icons randomly turn red when hovered over.

[image]

Whole desktop background turns red.

Comment: This does sound like a graphics driver issue. If you haven't done so, you shpuld try clean installing your graphics drivers. [Display Driver Uninstaller](http://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html) can wipe the drivers for you.

Comment: Do you have anything that automatically records your screen? Sometimes this software will blank the desktop background (normally to black), but this is only changing when that part is re-drawn.

Answer (score 0):

1. Update the video card driver from the official website of the manufacturer.
2. Turn off theme syncing in settings > accounts > sync.
3. Reset the wallpaper.
4. Create a new user account to check. It could make sure your user profile works fine.
5. Check it in Safe Mode.

Answer (score 0):

Control + windows + shift + b should fix then refresh ur desktop

Comment: Please be clear with your answer. Specify what is does also to the system.

Comment: If you're encountering display or graphics issues, you can press Ctrl+Shift+Win+B to force Windows to take action. This shortcut alerts the system to a potential graphics issue, which results in Windows restarting your video driver.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Control + Windows + Shift + B (Ctrl + ⊞ + Shift + B)** alerts Windows of an error or potential issue in the graphics card, for which it will then restart your graphics driver. When the graphics driver is restarted, it should work correctly, since it reloads everything with the driver.
2. If this key combination doesn't work, I recommend **using EVGA/NVIDIA's graphics driver installer to update your driver**, then restart your computer for the action to take full effect. This will replace the potentially corrupted/broken graphics driver with a newer one that is checked for bugs and errors.
3. If neither of those work, your graphics card may have a different issue, in which case I would **run a Hardware Diagnostic to look for faults in the system**.
4. If the issue still persists, and Hardware Diagnostics finds nothing wrong, **consult Microsoft Support or another trusted repair official to examine and diagnose your system**, as you could have a problem such as:

   - Multiple drivers are corrupted, broken, or missing
   - Your graphics card has a hardware issue that requires repair
   - Your motherboard may be damaged
   - Your graphics card slot is damaged

Answer (score 0):

Little late to the party here, but open Windows Settings (Win + I) and then go to "Personalization". Check to see if your background is actually set as a solid color. Adjust accordingly by selecting the desired background image.

Edit: I recently dealt with an issue where a user routinely deleted the image used to set their desktop background and for whatever reason it would cause the same issues here as OP. Despite being able to see the image on the desktop background, checking Personalization settings revealed that the background was set to a solid color . . . the same color that would appear after making a selection on the desktop.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It can be seen in his screenshot that this is not the case.

Comment: The Settings window is nowhere to be found in his screenshot. I recently dealt with an issue where a user routinely deleted the image used to set their desktop background and for whatever reason it would cause the same issues here as OP. Despite being able to see the image on the desktop background, checking Personalization settings revealed that the background was set to a solid color . . . the same color that would appear after making a selection on the desktop. I should have included that in my answer.